# Checking at least a single White space

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect if an input field has at least one white space?

This is what I tried

```
if( $('#myVal').val().indexOf(' ') != 0 ){
     ///has at least a single white space within the string
}
```

Comment: well that would fail if it is the first character. since 0 is the first character. It would be `!= -1` See docuemntation for more information on indexOf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must compare indexOf to -1 not 0

```
if( $('#myVal').val().indexOf(' ') != -1 ){
     ///has at least a single white space within the string
}
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kxqv8ayv/)

Comment: Note: @eltonkanami's solution is better as the question says 'white space', not just 'space'.  Using regex of `/\s/` will match other white-space characters like Tab, carriage-return, new-line etc.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it

```
/\s/.test($('#myVal').val())
```

Comment: Any reason for the `g` flag?